# polynomial modulo polynomial

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

If $h(x) = x^2 + 1$, $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ and $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, then 
$$
\begin{align}
g(x)h(x) \mod f(x) &\equiv
(x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 +1) \mod x^3 + x + 1 \\
&\equiv x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x  + 1 \mod x^3 +x + 1.
\end{align}
$$

Now apparently I go wrong here, because I assume you can subtract $xf(x)$ from this, resulting in $x^3 + x^2 +1$. But apparently this is wrong.

How should you do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, that you remain in the same equivalence class after subtracting $x f(x)$ (or any multiple of $f(x)$ for that matter).  However, you haven't reduced it to a *representative* of the equivalence class *of smallest degree,* which I'm guessing is the goal.  This is not explicitly stated.

Working modulo $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$ means that $x^3 + x + 1 \equiv 0$ or
$$
x^3 = -x - 1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
x^3 + x^2 + 1 \equiv (-x - 1) + x^2 +1 \equiv x^2 - x \mod f(x).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand it fully.